# FountainJS Angular2 installing component angular2-google-maps issue

Tags: google-maps, angular, typescript, yeoman, systemjs

I use fountainJS Angular2 generator with Typescript and Systems.js
for scaffolding the project. 
https://github.com/FountainJS/generator-fountain-angular2

But I got the issue, I can't add the component to the project.
When I put import `{GOOGLE_MAPS_DIRECTIVES}` 
I get this error

```
system.src.js:1057 GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2-google-maps/core/index.js 404 (Not Found)
```

[image]

I went through that 
https://angular-maps.com/docs/getting-started.html
'getting started' section and added some code to jspm.config.js file but I don't have angular-cli-build.js file inside my project.

My jspm.config.js

```
SystemJS.config({
  packageConfigPaths: [
    'npm:@*/*.json',
    'npm:*.json',
    'github:*/*.json'
  ],
  map: {
    'angular2-google-maps': 'node_modules/angular2-google-maps',
    '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common@2.0.0-rc.4',
    '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler@2.0.0-rc.4',
    '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core@2.0.0-rc.4',
    '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http@2.0.0-rc.4',
    '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser@2.0.0-rc.4',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0-rc.4',
    '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router@3.0.0-beta.2',
    'es6-shim': 'npm:es6-shim@0.35.1',
    'os': 'github:jspm/nodelibs-os@0.2.0-alpha',
    'process': 'github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.2.0-alpha',
    'reflect-metadata': 'npm:reflect-metadata@0.1.3',
    'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6',
    'ts': 'github:frankwallis/plugin-typescript@4.0.16',
    'zone.js': 'npm:zone.js@0.6.17'
  },
  packages: {
    'angular2-google-maps/core': {
      defaultExtension: 'js',
      main: 'index.js' // you can also use core.umd.js here, if you want faster loads
    },
    'github:frankwallis/plugin-typescript@4.0.16': {
      'map': {
        'typescript': 'npm:typescript@1.8.10'
      }
    },
    'github:jspm/nodelibs-os@0.2.0-alpha': {
      'map': {
        'os-browserify': 'npm:os-browserify@0.2.1'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `node_modules/angular2-google-maps/core/index.js 404 (Not Found)` because node_modules is not made available by web server used by `npm run serve`.

If you need node_modules to be accessible by client code, you have to add route for it in `conf/browsersync.conf.js`:

```
  routes: {
    '/node_modules': 'node_modules',
```

Alternatively, you could use jspm instead of npm to install angular2-google-maps:

```
jspm install angular2-google-maps
```

and jspm would modify jspm.config.js to add correct mapping for angular2-google-maps.

BUT, after 404 error is fixed, I'm getting now

```
system.src.js:123 Uncaught (in promise) Error: (SystemJS) core_1.NgModule is not a function
TypeError: core_1.NgModule is not a function
```

which probably means that the latest angular2-google-maps [is incompatible with angular2-rc4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39089942/ngmodule-is-not-a-function) installed by generator-fountain-angular2.